# How to export conversation history from Microsoft Communicator for Mac (2011)?

Tags: macos, microsoft

Got a new Mac & trying to move my stuff from old Mac. I am unable to find a way to move the conversation history of Microsoft Communicator 2011 (version 13.1.2) from old Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running this command,

```
find ~ -type f -exec grep "special search string" {} \; -print
```

I was able to find the Conversation history at

```
/Users/<my_mac_user_id>/Documents/Microsoft User Data/Microsoft Communicator History/<my_communicator_login_id>
```

Just copying the entire folder to new mac solved my problem.

"special search string" is an unique string you would have used while chatting with your friends/colleagues.